# What is the principal value of this number?

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all values of the logarithm of each of the following numbers and state the principal value. Put answers in the form a+ib.

1. $e^{i \pi /3}$

I have that it is equal to $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac12 i$.

I'm not sure how to state the principal value.

Comment: The question does not ask for the $a+ib$ form of $e^{i\pi/3},$ it asks for the $a+ib$ form of the ***logarithm*** of $e^{i\pi/3}.$ Like, "$e$ raised to WHAT POWER equals $e^{i\pi/3}?$ Now that's almost as easy as "who's buried in Grant's tomb". Not quite, because, as the question hints at, there are many values that work.

Comment: Hint $i^i=e^{i(pi/2+2pik)}$ for k in natural numbers. (why?) Then we denote the principal value to be equal to the value k=0. What does it mean to raise something to an imaginary power?

Comment: Google StackExchange LaTeX guide so that your formulae aren't long wordy sentences.

Comment: @shaihorowitz I would appreciate your help. I am having trouble

Answer (score 2):

$\ln(e^{i*\pi/3}) = i*\pi/3 + 2*\pi*k$ for integers k. This is because $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$